# sbt run only work if I select class not if I pass it as argument

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-flink

I have a project created from a template.  When I do `sbt run` I select a class with main and it runs.  But when I pass the class with `sbt "runMain com.mitzit.WordCount"` it fails.  How can I pass the class with main that I want to run from the command line?  I don't want to edit build.sbt

Steps to reproduce

get project:

```
sbt new tillrohrmann/flink-project.g8 \
  --name=sbt-flink-template \
  --organization=com.mitzit \
  --version=0.1 \
  --flink_version=1.7.0 \
  --scala=2.12.11
```

**This works**

run 
`sbt run`

```
Multiple main classes detected, select one to run:

 [1] com.mitzit.Job
 [2] com.mitzit.SocketTextStreamWordCount
 [3] com.mitzit.WordCount

Enter number: 3
```

`[success] Total time: 395 s, completed Apr 22, 2020 4:24:22 PM`

**This Fails**

`sbt "runMain com.mitzit.WordCount"`

```
[error] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/api/common/typeinfo/TypeInformation
[error]         at com.mitzit.WordCount.main(WordCount.scala)
```

How can I run a specific main without having to select it each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in the root project part of the Flink libraries are classified as `provided`

To overcome this issue this template project `tillrohrmann/flink-project.g8` is providing an utility sub-project `mainRunner` that simply edit the dependency configuration, removing the `provided` classifier to enable running it from IntelliJ (or sbt as you are asking)

you can simply run

```
sbt "mainRunner/runMain com.mitzit.WordCount"
```